# Facebook API to change password

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am doing a Facebook Interface that will allow user to login and view feed etc.

How do I let user to trigger a password change if need to be. I am currently using the access token after login by user for fetching the feeds etc.

However I don't see any API call for password change. Any idea which call to use or is it even possible?

Comment: That is of course not possible

Comment: now that would be the most unsecure and dangerous thing ever...

Comment: Ok noted. Thanks for the info.